# Disable inline edit in standard list view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, list-view

I have seen many questions regarding this but didn't find a proper solution.
I want to disable the inline edit (edit from the standard list view 'All') for an object(not for all the objects).
For that object, the new and edit button is overridden with a lightning aura component.
is there any existing solution for this issue?